# What's the correct way to check sql found condition in ILE RPG?

Tags: rpgle, db2-400, embedded-sql

When working with embedded SQL in RPG, you often end up with a cursor and a `dow`-loop for processing all rows in your result. The condition in the loop is somehow dependent on `SQLCOD` and/or `SQLSTT`, some globally available variables in an SQLRPGLE-program?

But what is the correct way of checking these values? Some suggest `SQLCOD = 0` others `not (SQLCOD = +100 or SQLSTT = '02000')`. One fails on all warnings, the other does not fail on some errors, so I'm not content.

To illustrate what I do with some code:

```
Pmain             B
D                 PI
Dmy_ds          E DS                  extname(SOME_TABLE)
D                                     qualified
 /free
  exec sql
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
      SELECT *
      FROM some_table;
  exec sql 
    OPEN cur;
  exec sql
    FETCH cur
     INTO :my_ds;
  dow sql_found();
      exec sql
        FETCH cur
         INTO :my_ds;
  enddo;
  exec sql
    CLOSE cur;
 /end-free
Pmain             E


Psql_found        B
D                 PI              N
 /free
  // insert return statement here...
 /end-free
Psql_found        E
```

I'm looking for the correct return statement here, that will make me go through all rows if no error occurs and lets me leave when an error occurs. Bonus points for some decent way to check for errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLSTATE is better, and recommended by IBM.

From IBM's InfoCenter [SQL Messages and Codes Reference: SQLCODE and SQLSTATE concepts](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzala%2Frzalaco.htm)

> SQLSTATE is the preferred standard return code.

SQLSTATE is 5 characters, with the first two bytes identifying a [class of conditions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzala%2Frzalaclass.htm).

- '00' = Unqualified Successful Completion
- '01' = Warning
- '02' = No Data

Anything else is an error.   I generally only check for '00'.

Simple.  Easy.  More portable.

Using SQLCODE often involves lists of codes which are, IMHO, less than developer friendly.

**Example:**

Personally, I generally include definitions and code like this:

```
 D xSQLState@      s               *   inz( %addr(SQLState) )
 D xSQLState       ds             5    based(xSQLState@)
 D  xSQLState2                    2a
 D   
 D Success_On_SQL  C                   const('00')
 D Warning_On_SQL  C                   const('01')
 D NoData_On_SQL   C                   const('02')
```

Then after any SQL operation, I generally check

```
   if xSQLState2 <> Success_On_Sql;
     someflag = true;
   endif;
```

Comment: Minor note... it's not totally true that "Anything else is an error" for SQLSTATE classes. Only classes reserved for DB2 (and defined as errors) are necessarily errors. Signaling 'K1001' for example would only be an error if the application handled it as an error.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to process the SQLCODEs you expect (as part of the expected processing) and to add exception code to handle the ones you don't.  One implementation:

```
  dow 1=1;  // forever
      exec sql
        FETCH cur
         INTO :my_ds;
  // normal exit         
  if sqlstt = SQL_NODATA;
    SFLEND = *on;        
    leave;               
  endif;                 

  // can't CAST a value
  if sqlstt = SQL_CAST;         // CAST error                               
    ... tell user there's an error and read another
    iter;                                                                  
  endif;                                                                   

  // decimal data error
  if sqlstt = SQL_DDE;
    tell user to call IT and stop reading
    leave;                                      
  endif;                                        


  // whoops! not expected at all.  Dump for post-mortem
  if sqlstt <> SQL_NORMAL;                             
    ... tell user to call IT and stop reading
    dump(a);                             
    leave;                                              
  endif;                                               

  // test for end of loop
  // filled subfile page?
  enddo;  // forever
```

With this type of implementation you have to intentionally leave the loop; whether you've filled a subfile page, loaded the highest element in an array or hit an error.  I'm not sure there is a single, generic implementation that will handle all circumstances.  Sometimes you might want to leave the read loop if you have a record lock and sometimes you want to issue a message and try again (for example).

Comment: Names that start with SQL are reserved by the precompiler.  See [Names in ILE RPG applications that use SQL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzajp%2Frzajprpiamco.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I did some more searching on the topic and found [something on IBM's site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzmstcksql.htm) (quote):

> ```
> The SQLCODE is also set by the database manager after each SQL 
> statement is executed as follows: 
>   - If SQLCODE = 0 and SQLWARN0 is blank, execution was successful.
>   - If SQLCODE = 100, no data was found. For example, a FETCH 
>     statement returned no data, because the cursor was positioned 
>     after the last row of the result table.
>   - If SQLCODE > 0 and not = 100, execution was successful with a 
>     warning.
>   - If SQLCODE = 0 and SQLWARN0 = 'W', execution was successful 
>     with a warning.
>   - If SQLCODE < 0, execution was not successful.
> ```

Which would lead me to an `sql_found()` like this:

```
Pfound_sql        B
D                 PI              N
 /free
  return (SQLCOD >= 0) and (SQLCOD<>100);
 /end-free
Pfound_sql        E
```

That should take care of the End of Data condition and fail on all errors. I'm not sure if there are some warnings that I should take care of (don't want to get trapped in an endless loop, if there is a warning that leads to not reading).

Comment: 1) I'd advise against using global variables (like SQLCOD) in a subprocedure.  What happens when you need to nest a FETCH loop inside another one?  When the inner loop reaches EOF it will inadvertently trip the exit on the outer loop too.  Pass SQLCOD as a parameter and that problem goes away.

Comment: 2) Swallowing errors (like SQLCOD<>100) is inadvisable.  What happens if it's a CAST error and you're losing data?

Comment: A conceivable benefit of defining a procedure for this purpose, is that one might perhaps also include generic logic to deal unexpected errors such as a CAST, in case you did not provide specific logic to handle them otherwise.  Eh?